# Trouble getting Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0 to coexist (using RVM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I've been struggling to get the most recent versions of Ruby and Rails running on my computer (using a mid-2007 Mac, running 10.7 OSX). I originally installed with the installer at installrails.com for the purpose of completing the Rails course at onemonthrails.com.

The installer didn't include the most recent versions of Ruby/Rails, so I upgraded each one and then checked the installed versions as you can see in the retyped input/output below (SO wouldn't let me post a screenshot):

```
userusers-MacBook:Downloads useruser$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-33 revision 39386) [x86_darwin10.8.0]
userusers-MacBook:Downloads useruser$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.2
userusers-MacBook:Downloads useruser$ rvm --default use 2.0.0
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
userusers-MacBook:Downloads useruser$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
userusers-MacBook:Downloads useruser$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

What happens when I try the `$ sudo gem install rails` is 1 of 2 things:

1) the command appears to run, but when I go to `$ rails -v` after its completion, I get the same message saying Rails is not installed, or

2) the command will run successfully, `$ rails -v` will show I'm running `Rails 4.0.0` but `$ ruby -v` will show I'm running `Ruby 1.9.3p352`. Asking it to default to `Ruby 2.0.0` (via `$ rvm --default 2.0.0`) causes Rails to disappear again (based on the fact `$ rails -v` will say "Rails is not currently installed on this system").

Does anyone have an idea as to what could be the issue/how to resolve this?

If I need to provide more info or reformulate the question, let me know. This is my first post on SO and I'm new to programming as well.

Answer (score 1):

When installing gems you should never use sudo because this causes many problems. What I would  do it try to get a clean install by first uninstalling rails and rvm. Install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) which helps install gems and their dependencies by running `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"` in terminal. Then install rvm with ruby and rails at the same time by entering `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --rails`. This should make it easy to install whatever versions you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have Homebrew already, so that's ready to go. As for the RVM uninstall, I did $ rvm implode (the only way I knew how to uninstall), and based on the output, pretty much every directory under /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems came back with "Permission denied" or a handful of "Directory not empty." 

Is that normal or do I have another problem here?

Comment: That sounds like a real problem maybe you originally installed rvm with sudo? Anyway try sudo rvm implode and don't use sudo when installing any of this stuff.